# Drupal 7 media module to replace swftools

Tags: video, cms, drupal, audio-streaming

I was using the [swftools](http://drupal.org/project/swftools) module for a Drupal 6 site. It was nice as you could place tokens of audio or video files in your text editor and it would be converted to a flash object for you when the page was rendered.

A port for drupal 7 has just started and is realistically probably months away.

What are similar modules for drupal 7 that people recommend using right now?

Some modules that are atleast in development are:

- [Media](http://drupal.org/project/media)
- [Video](http://drupal.org/project/video)
- [Media Front](http://drupal.org/project/mediafront)

Thanks.

**Edit:** I have been impressed with the [jplayer](http://www.jplayer.org) website. Since drupal has jquery bundled, this might be a good fit. There is a module for D6 to wrap jplayer, but none for 7. I will try the library out out and let you know if it was easy to integrate or not.

Comment: I assume, this should be posted in http://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [JPlayer](http://drupal.org/project/jplayer) module. It's for Drupal 7 and this module provides a wrapper around the jPlayer JavaScript library.

Also [Flowplayer](http://drupal.org/project/flowplayer) has a good benefits (module provides integration with the GPL licensed Flowplayer for Flash video playback).

Comment: +1 JPlayer for D7 was not in development when I asked my question last year but I imagine it would work - I've been away from drupal lately.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't release that this question was from last year:) Better later, than never:)